# Deleting entities through navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I usually have the main entity I'm deleting but in this instance what I'm trying to delete it through a navigation property

```
var person = await dbContext.Person
                    .Include(x => x.Phone)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.PersonKey == key, cancellationToken);

person.Phones.Remove(phoneToDelete);

await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I got the following exception on `SaveChangesAsync()`

`Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The association between entity types 'Person' and 'Phone' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use`

The following code does work:

```
dbContext.Remove(phoneToDelete);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

So of course I did get it working but I thought the original code should work and want to understand why it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is hinting to the issue: `'The association between entity types 'Person' and 'Phone' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable.`

If your `Person` model has an `int PhoneId` property which acts as the foreign key for `Phone`, you won't be able to delete the `Phone` entry associated with the `Person`.

If you want to be able to do that, you'll need to change your `Person` model to `int? PhoneId`, which makes it `nullable` and will allow you to delete the associated entry.

The reason, in case it wasn't clear, is that the `int` type cannot hold a `null` value, which is what would be left when deleting `Phone`. Meanwhile, `int?` can hold a `null` value, and thus allows deleting `Phone` and leaving `PhoneId = null`.

Comment: Thanks one of our Architects already filled me into the details. If you go through a navigation property and try to remove an entity all your doing is telling EF to remove the association (which since its required isn't allowed) not to remove the entity from the database which is why l got the error